# Get img from browser resources

Tags: java, browser, web-scraping

I'm writing a java web application that get image from other website and post it on my own one.
I need to take an image created by google maps api from a particular site, of course I can't download it with tool like selenium because I can't click on it; so I need to get image from firefox cache. How Can I do it???
I would like to reach the directory image /resources/cms/images.

http://www.protezionecivile.gov.it/jcms/it/view_bcr.wp?contentId=BCR57314&day=domani

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I fully understood your request, but maybe with JSOUP you could parse the site and isolate the images you want to download

Comment: No, probably my question is not clear. I have already used jsoup and selenium to scraping a website, but I found out that The website contains an image generated by google maps api and inested into a div tag (class=" map_canvas"). Therefore I have to pick the image from my directory temp of my browser when I access to it. Now do you know how can or where is the right directory of firefox or chrome that hold the image displyaed

Comment: We'll need a link to further help you

Comment: http://www.protezionecivile.gov.it/jcms/it/view_bcr.wp?contentId=BCR57314&day=domani